# CDN Links and missing http:

Tags: url, hyperlink, protocols, cdn

A questiona I am asking myself since my entrance into web development is, why is the protocol (i.e. 'http:') missing in almost every CDN link?

Comment: what's a "cdn link"?

Comment: Content Delivery Network.
Like Google Hosted libraries.

Answer (score 0):

***YES***, Its recommended (better way) that do not use **http://** or **https://** with cd urls because cdn links are enough smart to decide that what exactly need to be used.

> `//` will give it a realtive protocol.

**Meaning** that if you are accessing `http://example.com` then the cdn link will also use `http://` whereas if you are accessing `https://example.com` then the cdn link will use `https://` as well.

So use as below example:-

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 0):

Protocol-relative URL has nothing to do with CDN. This article contains good information about protocol-relative URL: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/